# How to get UPDATE SQL commands working in VB.net and MySQL?

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim con As New MySqlConnection("host=localhost; username=root; password=; database=wh_db")
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand
    Dim dr As MySqlDataReader

    con.Open()
    cmd.Connection = con
    cmd.CommandText = " select pass from user where pass ='" & oldpass.Text & "'"

    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
    If dr.HasRows Then

        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.CommandText = " UPDATE user SET pass ='" & newpass.Text & "' where user = '" & user.Text & "'"

    Else
        MsgBox("Password is not correct")

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What error are you getting? You should also really use parameters to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: Someone can enter any available password from the database and will be able to change their password... I would also suggest you hash the passwords.

Comment: Unclear, voting to close.

Answer (score 1):

I've not used MySQL for a while but have a look at this. It should give you some start into what you're after:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim dr As MySqlDataReader

    Using con As New MySqlConnection(yourConnectionString),
          cmd As New MySQLCommand("SELECT pass FROM user WHERE pass = @pass", con)

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@pass", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = oldpass.Text

        con.open()

        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

    End Using

    If dr.HasRows Then

        Using con As New MySqlConnection(yourConnectionString),
              cmd As New MySQLCommand("UPDATE user SET pass = @pass WHERE user = @user", con)

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@pass", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = newpass.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@user", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = user.Text

            con.open()

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        End Using

    Else
        MsgBox("Password is not correct")
    End If
End Sub
```

The reason you're not updating is because you haven't told the command to update. I've also implemented [Using](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx) which I suggest you do and also look at parameters to stop SQL injection.

I've separated both statements into two `Using` statements as I feel this would be better rather than attempting to reuse the same object for both the `SELECT` and `UPDATE` command.

Comment: Have to give me a bit more information than that. What is the error?